Why does a double beam spectrophotometer need baseline correction?
I was trying to find the answer in the web, but I don't really understand it. From my understanding, the reference cuvette should work as a blank and subtract any absorbance from the solvent/matrix and also correct any real time fluctuations of light intensity or detector output. I've read about baseline drift but I can't really understand the need of measuring the baseline in this case.

Meh, these analytic dudes would like to calibrate everything! ;p

There are all sorts of things that can throw off one reading or the other - eg slight differences in the cuvette. The baseline correction just makes sure that you start at 0 even if the difference in absorbance between the two is non-zero when the same solution is in both.

also, the baseline correction isn't "needed", just a convenient option. Typically you can turn it off in the software.

There are several issues which require baseline correction in any optical spectroscopic measurement (IR, UV-Vis etc.).
At an elementary level, students think that the light source, monochromator, and the detector are perfect in the sense that no matter what wavelength they choose, the detector response will be the same. Sadly, the light detectors do not respond identically to all wavelengths from 200-700 nm. The double spectrophotometer basically compensates for light source fluctuations and intensity drifts. Also, the two cuvet are not optically the same, until and unless you buy an expensive optically matched pair. By optical matching we mean the cuvets have same reflection, refraction and transmission properties. It requires a lot of precision manufacturing. Ordinary lab cuvets, esp. for labs, are not optically matched.
The double beam instrument needs baseline correction to account for all real-life these imperfections. Actually you should do an experiment, and measure UV-Vis spectrum of any food dye heavily diluted with water with and without baseline correction. Do a full scan from 200-700 nm and notice the differences in the shape of the spectrum and mark any artifacts. You will see there will a sharp discontinuity when the light sources switch from visible (tungsten lamp) to UV (D2 lamp) even on a double beam instrument when there was no baseline correction. Some modern UV-Vis spectrophotometers use a xenon arc lamp. The absorbance will be offset for many wavelengths. Seeing is believing and this experiment will not take more than 5 min.
